# I am Looking for sample Spring MVC with Cassandra example

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, cassandra, nosql

1. Where Can I purchase Spring MVC Projects with Cassandra Database.
2. I am looking for sample Spring MVC with Cassandra project. I see many example with Spring and Cassandra but not with Spring MVC. Just wanted to see configuration and one transaction with Cassandra.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You do know it is your job to make that research right?

Comment: 1. Spring MVC doesn't depend on any storage(Cassandra/Mongo/MySql), you can use it like in any tutorial for any DB.
2. So you just can go throug Spring Data tutorial for Cassandra(like http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial) and do it in your own way.